# Code Camper vs. Code Camper Jump Start

Tags: less, single-page-application, hottowel

I'm currently following the great courses from John Papa. I've just checked 'Code Camper' and 'Code Camper Jump Start'.
Assuming the latter is better than the former, there are some technologies omitted from the latter one.
For example `Sammy` is not directly used due to use of `Durandal`.

But some other things omitted which I cant understand the reason.
For example `LESS` and `Templates` are not being used in the latter.

Are these techniques some sort of deprecated? Is CCJS just a simple but more structured version of CC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter (Jump-Start) is a beginner level course that just focuses on the core parts of a SPA. The focus is on the client, so no LESS on the server, no UoW, no Repository, etc.

See my post for more info http://www.johnpapa.net/spajs01

Comment: is there any code sample with CRUD operations in intermediate level you given sample code